# Setting state in zustand persist middleware causing infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-state-management, zustand

```
import create from 'zustand';
import createContext from 'zustand/context';
import { persist } from 'zustand/middleware';

let store;

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  cart: {
    cartItems: {},
    invoiceData: {},
    count: 0,
  },
};

const zustandContext = createContext();
export const Provider = zustandContext.Provider;
// An example of how to get types
/** @type {import('zustand/index').UseStore<typeof initialState>} */
export const useStore = zustandContext.useStore;

export const initializeStore = (preloadedState = {}) => {
  return create(
    persist(
      (set, get) => ({
        ...initialState,
        ...preloadedState,

        updateCart: (cartData) => {
          set({
            cart: cartData,
          });
        },
        setLoading: (val) => {
          set({
            loading: val,
          });
        },
        modifyCart: (product, qty, type) => {
          const cartData = get().cart;

          // cart operations

          set({
            cart: tmpCartData,
          });
        },
      }),
      {
        name: 'cartData',
      }
    )
  );
};

export function useCreateStore(initialState) {
  const [cartData, setCartData] = useState(null);

  const [userCart, setCart] = useLocalStorage('cartData', {});
  const { state: { cart = {} } = {} } = userCart;

  
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    return () => initializeStore(initialState);
  }

  
  store = store ?? initializeStore(initialState);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (initialState && store) {
      store.setState({
        ...store.getState(),
        ...initialState,
      });
    }
  }, [initialState]);


  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      store.setState({
        ...store.getState(),
        cart: { ...cart },
        loading: true,
      });
      
      
    })();
  }, []);

  return () => store;
}
```

This code is inspired by Zustand documentation and by the NextJS and Zustand boilerplate. I need to sync this data with the browser's localstorage. However, calling the 'set' method inside modifyCart causes an infinite render. I have not found enough documentations regarding this.
How should I go about debugging such an issue?